# Vuetify Speed up a v-Select / v-Overflow-button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to reduce the response time between clicking on an Vuetify `<v-select>` or a `<v-overflow-btn>` and it showing the options? I find it slow to respond, which for me at least, breaks my UI experience a bit.

Ideally I'd have close to the speed of a good-old plain `<select>` dropdown box.

*Alternatively,* is it possible to "turn off" the v-select tag, so I could use a different component such as *Vue-Select* (https://vue-select.org/), which uses the same `v-select` tag name (and is much faster to respond).

**Edit:** I'm going to split off the second part (starting with the word *Alternatively*) into a separate question. As for the first part, apparently not everyone is experiencing this, but on my desktop Chrome the Vuetify select is definiatly feeling "sluggish", compared to other non-Vuetify select components. If there are no new answers, I'll eventually accept Steven Spungin answer, as it has general and correct hints on speeding up a slow select component.

Comment: Is the delay only on touch devices?  How many items are in the options list?

Comment: No, regular desktop, almost empty list. It's not a problem with my site, it's default Vuetify behaviour, it's the same sluggish response in their examples page: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects.

Comment: I am running chrome on an ipad and see no delay at all on the demo site.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the `300ms tap delay`, dynamically loading items, and using a query filter, you can speed up the `v-select`.

Comment: How to turn that off? The site already has a `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`